# phpaggcat example.php is giving me a service unavailable error

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm trying to connect to intuit's CAD api using phpaggcat library (https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat) When I run their example, I'm getting a Service Unavailable Error when I run the example.php file. My stack is ubuntu/php/codeigniter. Any thoughts on how I could debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you are able to call CAD endpoints using OPENSssl generated keys.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

Service status page indicates that yesterday, there were some issues in CAD service.

http://developer-status.intuit.com/

Thanks